# How to fix "from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2" error in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

My teammates and I get the following error when we try to run the code for our class project. We used this colab notebook to install caffe before, but still ran into the error: https://colab.research.google.com/github/Huxwell/caffe-colab/blob/main/caffe_details.ipynb#scrollTo=vCy0jVs6Bo7G. We tried every possible option, but still no luck. :// Anyone got an idea of how can we resolve this error?

from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2

Comment: Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You shouldn't link to code or include images of the code. Instead, type the code directly into the question body.